# Fluent Validation use of LINQ let?

Tags: c#, linq, fluentvalidation

I'm trying to create a validation rule whereby I can pass in two parameters into a method called by Must()

My models;

```
public class Make
{
    public int MakeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Car[] Cars { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Validator

```
public class MakeValidator : AbstractValidator<Make>
{
    public MakeValidator()
    {
        When(car => car.Cars != null && car.Cars.Any(), () =>
        {               
            RuleFor(car => car.Car)
                .Must(car => ValidateCar(car.CarId, MakeId)
                .WithMessage("Invalid Car");
        });
    }

    public bool ValidateCar(Car[] Cars, int makeId)
    {
        foreach (var car in Cars)
        {
            // *** internal logic ***
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: And why does a certain car have multiple Makes?

Comment: @lc "can we grab the CardId here? this line will break", but still, poorly formatted question.

Comment: @wonea I'd suggest removing the question from code comments and make it more explicit, perhaps demonstrate it working with the LINQ query syntax (if it does at all), or any attempts you have made and why they didn't work.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Agreed, I've revised the question. Should have taken lunch before hammering it out.

Comment: @wonea Unfortunately, it looks like you've actually removed the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
Must((y, x) =>
```

instead of

```
Must(x =>
```

where `y` represents your class, and `x` your property

so to make things clearer

```
.Must((car, make) => ValidateCarMake(make, car.CarId)
```

**EDIT**

from the signature of your `ValidateCarMake` method, it should be

either

```
RuleFor(car => car.Makes)
     .Must((car, make) => ValidateCarMake(make, car.CarId)
     .WithMessage("Invalid Car Make");
```

or

```
RuleFor(car => car.Make)
      .Must((car, make) => ValidateCarMake(car.Makes, car.CarId)
      .WithMessage("Invalid Car Make");
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my confusing question with a clear answer. Very much appreciated. Great insight.